# include existing youtube video in my own youtube account

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to add to my youtube account a video I liked in youtube without having to upload it?

This is for an application i´m developing... I´m looking for something similar to share on twitter feature.

But any help is welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Ummm... you shouldn't be copying videos like that. Do you want to add it as a favorite instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can add it as a favourite, as Yuliy has said, or you can create yourself a channel, add a playlist to that channel, then add the video in a similar way to the playlist.

Doing it this way means you can 'see' it from the API(getplaylists, getplaylist)... But, if the original author decides to take the video down, then of course it will disappear from your channel page as well (or more likely say 'this video has been removed by the user').

You cant keep a 'copy' of the video like this.

Comment: Did this help? If so, please mark as answered - That way, more people are likely to help you....